# Why does many of Jquery animation or effects works in Internet Explorer lower versions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have just started using jquery, and some effects or functions like slide up, slide down works properly in Internet Explorer and when i try the same with CSS3 it works properly in Chrome, Firefox and other webkit, opera, mozilla browsers but why does that effects don't work in Internet Explorer.

Please don't say me that CSS3 dosen't support Internet Explorer lower versions as i too know about it. 
And lastly: Will effects created using Javascript will work in Internet Explorer lower versions ?

Comment: I think your first and last questions answer each other.

Comment: When you choose to use a technology, check the browser support against the browser use of your target market.

Comment: You guys mean that effects created using Javascript will work in IE too ?

Comment: @AshwinPathak: That completely depends on what the Javascript does.  The only answer to your question is "Yes; IE does support Javascript".

Comment: You said yourself that they work in IE, and you're asking why, right?

Comment: ok...great, just now tried it, it works :D thanks for your support  :D

Answer (score 2):

jQuery animations do not use CSS animations; instead, they manually change CSS properties on a timer.

They will work on any browser that jQuery supports.

Comment: Providing someone is not using jQuery to implement a CSS3 animation (i've seen it happen).

Comment: @Vector: Those aren't **jQuery** animation (=== `.animate()`)

Comment: For exmaple: if i created an effect using jquery by looping it or adding a timer will it work properly in IE, asking because i never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery calculate every new value in his code and change the static CSS like `left` every X ms. If the changed value is supported by the broswer, it will work.

Here a little exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/PPXmE/

CSS3 animation is a new implementation which we could say do the same calculs, but faster. It is only new broswer that can read them.